# CALayer/CABasicAnimation opacity animation cache?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation

I've got a View that appears as a dialog and I am animating its opacity when I want it to be removed from the parent view.

I'm using the following code to change its opacity via a CABasicAnimation:

```
CALayer *opacityOutLayer = sheetView.layer;
CABasicAnimation *fadeOutAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
fadeOutAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
fadeOutAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
fadeOutAnimation.duration = 0.255;
[opacityOutLayer addAnimation:fadeOutAnimation forKey:@"opacity"];
```

This looks perfect in the simulator, but not very smooth on a device. Is there any way to cache the animation (like using UIView transition cache:YES)?

I'm sure this is pretty simple but after searching the documentation and CALayer class info I can't find anything to cache it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try setting `layer.shouldRasterize = YES;` and see if that improves performance.

But note that `shouldRasterize` will slow down compositing considerably as soon as the contents of your layer change. So you should only enable it for a certain animation and then disable it again.

Comment: Also had a slight lag from a shadow applied to a UITextView inside the sheet and I also rasterized that layer too and its now as smooth as silk. Thank you again!

Comment: Great. I have added a warning to my answer to not enable `shouldRasterize` permanently. There is a reason it's disabled by default.